# Cron job appendOutputTo not append anything in Laravel

Tags: laravel, cron, scheduled-tasks, scheduler, scheduling

I have a problem in my project. I cannot append output in my cron job.
Here is my code

```
<?php
namespace App\Console;
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel {
    protected $commands = [
        '\App\Console\Commands\CronEmail'
    ];
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule) {    
        $schedule->command('app:CronEmail')->everyMinute()->appendOutputTo(public_path("cron.log"))->emailOutputTo('my email address');
    }
    protected function commands() {
        $this->load(__DIR__ . '/Commands');
        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

But this is not append output to my file, Also it does not send output to my email address

Comment: Are you sure the command is getting executed?

Comment: Yes my command is executed. I checked it multiple times @Mozammil

Comment: Do you have write access to the public folder? Since, typically `storage` folder is more open, did you try `->appendOutputTo(storage_path('cron.log'))` and see if you find it under `storage`?

Comment: @Mozammil Yes I tried `->appendOutputTo(storage_path('cron.log'))` but without success

Comment: aany updates or anyone can help us?
im also get this issue in ubuntu  server

Comment: Can someone tell me what is the location of cron.log file. Because in my case it is working.

Comment: I just only don't know how to use appendOutputTo option with schedule a job. Can someone help me out by schedule a job and append output to a file.